# I want to change path of ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport to my External Drive

Tags: ios, xcode, path, crash-reports, symbolicatecrash

When we connect any iOS device to MAC OS X, by default Xcode copy device info into `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport` path. I want that files for symbolicate crash log. But my MAC derive is almost full only 1 GB avaialble. So I want to move `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport` to my External drive so my symbolication works well. So can any one please suggest me some way to change path. I have try to change the developer directory but that's not work.

Any help or hint will be appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: You haven't mentioned how you tried to change the directory, and what does not work.

Comment: I have try with sudo xcode-select -s /<MY_PATH>/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer command.

With the above command it's change the command line tools but not actual "Developer" directory path.

Comment: You can change the path inside of Xcode preferences I believe: `Preferences` > `Locations`, then set it to your external drive.

Comment: Inside the Xcode preferences we can change path of "Derived Data" and "Archives" . Don't how how we can change path of "Developer" directory.

Comment: Did you figure this out? still struggling..

Answer (score 0):

Until Xcode 10 i was able to symlink the whole Developer folder on an external drive, *e.g.*:

```
ln -s /Volumes/_/Library/Developer/Xcode /Users/_/Library/Developer/Xcode
```

Comment: I tried the same thing on my own accord. It results in build errors like `Failed to find or create execution context for description '<IBCocoaTouchPlatformToolDescription: 0x1107bee90> System content for IBCocoaTouchFramework-EightAndLater <IBScaleFactorDeviceTypeDescription: 0x1107b8f80> scaleFactor=2x, renderMode.identifier=(null)'.` on Xcode 12.x for me.